# iOS Get all NSArray into one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I've NSArray with NSArray in. I would like to get all NSArray into one.

I think there is a simple function to use, isn't it ?

Here is what I receive :

```
(
        (
        n0eGi1KJWq,
        KHGeW32548,
    ),
        (
        n0eGi1KJWq
    )
)
```

I would like to get :

```
(
        n0eGi1KJWq,
        KHGeW32548,
        n0eGi1KJWq
)
```

Comment: The function you're looking for is `flatMap`.

Comment: @keithbhunter Thanks man, but I'm using Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simply loop can be used to create a new array:

```
NSArray *mainArray = ... // the array containing the other arrays
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *innerArray in mainArray) {
    [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:innerArray];
}
```

At this point `finalArray` will have all of the objects from all of the other arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `@unionOfArrays` for this purpose:

```
NSArray *flatArray = [array valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

If you need a deeper flattening (for three dimensional array), use it twice:

```
NSArray *flatArray = [array valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.self.@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

Comment: Nice, but not really dynamic :/

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? It's not about the amount of arrays in your root array, but rather the deepness. Second example is for array of arrays of arrays ;)

Comment: ohhhh ok ! Coool 

Comment: It's just a bit shorter solution than the accepted one, but it does exactly the same :)

Comment: I didn't understand, but U're right it's simple and easy !